# setPreferredOrientations based on device screen size [Flutter]

Tags: flutter

I want to set orientation portrait only for small screen devices. At the moment I set everything to portrait orientation like so:

```dart
Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

How can I set portrait orientation **only** if screen width is below a certain pixel count? (eg: 500px)

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use **MediaQueryData.fromWindow** to get get the size. You can use it to get the scren width.

```dart
Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  final double screenWidth = MediaQueryData.fromWindow(WidgetsBinding.instance.window).size.width;
  if (screenWidth < 500) {
    await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
  }

  runApp(MyApp());
}
```